# Reading Durations of signal train

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-zero, rpi.gpio, signal

I am receiving a signal train of alternate high low pulses and trying to read it on Raspberry Pi Zero W. I have enabled the one wire pin(GPIO-4) and used that pin to read the pulses.
I am reading the external pulse that I have connected to GPIO4.
I have checked in the oscilloscope and so when I am reading the same through raspberry pi it seems like it is skipping some durations.

Below is my code in Python and the screenshot of the oscilloscope:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Pin configuration
input_pin = 4  # Use the GPIO pin number you're connecting to

# Initialize GPIO settings
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(input_pin, GPIO.IN)

# Main loop to receive data
try:
    while True:
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(input_pin, GPIO.FALLING)
        low_start_time = time.time()
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(input_pin, GPIO.RISING)
        low_duration = (time.time() - low_start_time)*1000
        print("low", low_duration)
        
        high_start_time = time.time()
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(input_pin, GPIO.FALLING)
        high_duration = (time.time() - high_start_time)*1000
        print("high", high_duration)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

The low and high durations are totally different from what I receive in the oscilloscope.
There is a long pulse of low_duration of more than 50ms and so I am comparing it that way by taking the long pulse into consideration.

I am not able to figure out why am I skipping pulse, or is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: What does enabling the 1-wire pin mean?  If you have enabled the 1-wire bus on GPIO4 the system will generate 1-wire traffic on GPIO4.  Are you trying to monitor the system generated 1-wire traffic or are you generating signals externally?  Please EDIT your question to clarify.

Comment: I have edited my question. i have enabled 1 wire interface in raspberry pi config, and i am giving external signal to it. I just want to know the  durations. should i disable the one wire interface and then measure?

Comment: You should not enable the 1-wire bus unless you have connected a 1-wire device.

Comment: What voltages are these pulses?

Comment: `print("low", low_duration)` takes time to execute

Comment: @CoderMike these voltage from the pin(external that is generating these pulses) varries between 1.5 to 1.9v.

Comment: Those voltages probably won’t be detected by a gpio pin. They should be 0V or 3.3V.

Comment: @jsotola then how can I know if its reading correct.

Comment: @CoderMike how can i detect these then, which pin and what configuration should i use.? the frames continue after 480ms as i see in the oscilloscope.

Comment: This has become a signal conditioning question.  So  off topic here.  Run [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py) or [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html)

Comment: You would either need to convert your signal to 0V (low pulse) or 3.3V (high pulse) or maybe use a ADC to read the voltage.

Comment: can I not read these pulses using the interrupt that would detect the rising and falling edge and then calculate the duration

Comment: No, because a GPIO pin will only detect 0V or 3.3V - neither of which you are providing!

Comment: @CoderMike in oscilloscope Vpp shows 5.20v. when I measure the voltage from the pin of the external device through multimeter it varies between 1.2 to 1.9.

Comment: I suggest you try asking how to convert that pulse to something a pi can read here https://forums.raspberrypi.com/

Comment: i did get the durations using the pigpio. i will be asking my further doubts in the forum. thank you @CoderMike